# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+3)^{\sqrt{n+1}}}{(n+1)^{\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have no idea how to find a limit of sequence
 $$a_n= \frac{(n+3)^{\sqrt{n+1}}}{(n+1)^{\sqrt{n}}}$$. I think that it can be easily bounded by 1 from down, but this shows only $1≤a_n$. I think also it can be shown quite easily that we need only to show that limit of a sequence $n^{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}$ is equal to $1$, I am unable to show that too.

Comment: is this $$\sqrt{(n+1)}$$ or $$\sqrt{(n)}+1$$ in the exponent?

Comment: It is $\sqrt{(n+1)}$ in exponent of numerator. This sequence has limit equal to 1, but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: can you use L'Hospital?

Comment: No, it was on my exam before L'Hospital.

Answer (score 1):

shows that using conjugation that 
\begin{split}
a_n=\frac{(n+3)^{\sqrt{n+1}}}{(n+1)^{\sqrt{n}}} &= &\exp \left( {\sqrt{n+1}}\ln(n+3)- {\sqrt{n}}\ln(n+1)\right)\\
&=& \exp \left( \ln(n+3)\color{red}{\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)}+\sqrt{n}[\color{blue}{\ln(n+3)-\ln(n+1)} ]\right)\\ 
&=& \exp \left( \frac{\ln(n+3)}{\color{red}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}}+\sqrt{n}\color{blue}{\ln\frac{n+3}{n+1}}\right)\\
\end{split}

On the other hand, we have 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\ln\frac{n+3}{n+1} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\times\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{n+1}\right)}{\frac{2}{n+1}} = 0\times1= 0$$
Given that,  $\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}\to 0$ as $x\to0$
whereas
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln(n+3)}{\sqrt{(n+1)}+\sqrt{n}} =\lim_{n\to \infty} 2\frac{\ln\sqrt{n+3}}{\sqrt{n+3}}\times \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{n}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1}= 2\times0\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=0 $$

Given that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x} = 0$$
so $$\color{brown}{\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n =\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+3)^{\sqrt{n+1}}}{(n+1)^{\sqrt{n}}}=1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Few of the steps/limits here require justification,I'll leave that to you,if you need more help feel free to comment.
$$a_n=\frac{\frac{(n+3)^\sqrt{n+1}}{n^\sqrt{n}}}{(1+\frac1n)^\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\frac{(n+3)^\sqrt{n+1}}{n^{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n+1}}}}{(1+\frac1n)^\sqrt{n}}=\frac{(1+\frac3n)^{\sqrt{n+1}}}{n^{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}}(1+\frac1n)^\sqrt{n}}$$
Lets find $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}}$ first notice
$$\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}=\frac{(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1})(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}^2-\sqrt{n+1}^2}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}\\\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}}\\\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=0$$
I rewrote $n^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}}$ as $e^{\ln(n^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}})}$
Also
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}((1+\frac1n)^n)^{1/\sqrt{n}}=1$$
Almost analogous it can be shown that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac3n)^{\sqrt{n+1}}=1$$
Combining that together we get that $\lim a_n=1$

Comment: Thanks, great answer, seems like exactly what I was looking for, but I have one question. I still can't see why $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}}=1$$. Could you explain that in more detail?

Comment: @Shingle I edited my post hope it's clear now.

Comment: Yes, now everything is great.